# Por que o selenium não lê corretamente meu arquivo excel?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

```
import email
import pandas as pd  # PARA LER ARQUIVO EXCEL
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
uc.install()
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver  # NAVEGADOR
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  # ACHAR OS ELEMENTOS
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  # PARA DIGITAR

nome_arquivo = "emailteste1.xlsx"
url_login = "https://login.aliexpress.com/"

 = ._(_)
   ,   .():
  (": " + () + "    " + [""])

_ = {"": " "}
_ = .()
_.__("", _)
_._("--")

 = .(_=_)
.(_)


time.sleep(3)

elemento_texto_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fm-login-id"]')
elemento_texto_senha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fm-login-password"]')
elemento_enviar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[2]/span")

elemento_texto_email.send_keys(row["email"])
time.sleep(1)
elemento_texto_senha.send_keys(row["senha"])
time.sleep (2)

elemento_enviar.click()
#driver.quit()
```

quando este codigo

```
 = ._(_)
   ,   .():
  (": " + () + "    " + [""])
```

esta sozinho ele executa de um a um as linhas do meu arquivo xlxs, mas quando eu adiciono

```
_ = {"": " "}
_ = .()
_.__("", _)
_._("--")

 = .(_=_)
.(_)
```

ele lê tudo de uma vez e executa somente a última linha do meu arquivo

Comment: eu quero que o navegador abra em modo mobile, faça o login, va para um site, aperte um botão, feche e faça login com o proximo email, isso é possivel ? visto que o selenium não consegue ler linha por linha quando o google abre em modo mobile

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom Douglas, Primeiramente é bom entender o que cada import esta fazendo em seu código, o selenium server para teste de aplicações web e automações, quem está lendo a planilha é o pandas, todos eles usando python como core para rodar os códigos dessa biblioteca.
Segundo, o problema no seu código esta na indentarão.

A programação funciona de forma com que você da ordens para que seu computador execute os comando.
Analisando seus comandos podemos perceber que você manda executar o loop e depois executa os comando selenium fora do laço de repetição. sugiro a leitura dessa referente a [laços de repetição](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

para corrigir seu erro você precisa primeiro criar o for que significa "para" então você terá que ler, para cada linha em minha tabela faça algo entende?

para aplicar essa alteração apenas indente seu código dessa forma:

```
nome_arquivo = "emailteste1.xlsx"
url_login = "https://login.aliexpress.com/"

 = ._(_)
 ,   .():
    (": " + () + "    " + [""])

    _ = {"": " "}
    _ = .()
    _.__("", _)
    _._("--")
    
     = .(_=_)
    .(_)
    
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    elemento_texto_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fm-login-id"]')
    elemento_texto_senha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fm-login-password"]')
    elemento_enviar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[2]/span")
    
    elemento_texto_email.send_keys(row["email"])
    time.sleep(1)
    elemento_texto_senha.send_keys(row["senha"])
    time.sleep (2)
    
    elemento_enviar.click()
```

dessa forma para cada linha de sua planilha o python irá ler sua planilha pegar a linha referenciada e substituir na variável local do for.

Comment: muito obrigado, não percebi que eu tinha deixado os codigos sem o espaço para o for, fiquei horas pensando nisso e não percebi que deixei esse erro passar, muito obrigado. eu tenho mais uma duvida, nesse caso, abre uma aba faz o login e abre outra aba, como fazer para abrir uma aba, fazer login, fechar e seguir, pois quero colocar muitos emails no arquivo excel e não da pra abrir 100 chrome no meu computador

Comment: que bom que a resposta ajudou, se puder marcar como certa me ajudaria muito com a pontuação aqui no stackoverflow, agora para trocar a aba voce terá q fazer algo parecido com isso `drive.switch_to_window()` para facilitar tem esses exemplos no  acervo lima [https://acervolima.com/abrindo-e-fechando-guias-usando-o-selenium/#:~:text=Abrindo%20uma%20nova%20guia%20usando%20Selenium&text=O%20método%20executescript()%20do,switch_to_window()%20.]

Comment: obrigado, vou testar agora, mas só uma pergunta kkkkk sou novo no site, como eu marco a resposta como correta ?

Comment: Na minha resposta vai ter um simbolo de correto, em cinza voce clica nele para ficar verde, perto da setinha para cima e para baixo

Comment: normal eu acho o stackoverflow um pouco duro com os iniciantes, mas e bom para a gente acostumar com o mundo ashuahsu

Comment: kkkkkkkkk verdade, ja dei a resposta como certa mt obg

Comment: mas agora mais uma duvida kkkkkkkkkk, o aliexpress limita a quantidade que login de cada ip pra 4, dps de vc fazer login com 4 contas usando o msm ip eles colocam um captcha para ser resolvido, nesse caso, é possivel depois do for repetir o processo 4 vezes eu pedir para ele aguarda x segundos ? pretendo rotear internet do celular e usar um autoclick para ir ligando e desligando o modo avião, para assim mudar o ip, mas n sei como fazer para esperar esse tempo dps de rodar 4 vezes

Comment: cara tem sim, usa o `import time` e  `time.sleep(<segundos que vc quer esperar>)`

Comment: mas como eu defino especificamente pra esperar dps de 4 açoes, pq se eu der um time.sleep(60) ele vai esperar 60 segundos antes de fazer td de novo, to procurando mas se eu n achar nd vou só tentar trocar o ip a cada vez, mas isso vai diminuir muito a velocidade do bot, por isso quero definir pra só na 4 vez q for repetir o processo

Comment: verifica se seu index é múltiplos de 4 se ele for 4 8 12 ele espera o tempo, ou vc pode fazer comandos para voltar em vez de fechar a conexão e logar de novo

Comment: como eu verifico se o index é multiplo de 4, desculpa perguntar kkkkkkkk sou bem leigo, fiz um robo de pyautogui e essa foi minha unica exp com esse tipo de coisa

Comment: Se o index divido por 4 for um numero inteiro ele é

Comment: Não entendi kkkkkk mas obrigado msm assim, vc me ajudou mt, pro meu bot ficar pronto só falta eu conseguir mudar de ip msm

Comment: blz, mas seria simples faz o seguinte pega o index divide por 4, verifica o tipo do resultado se for float nao é divisivel por 4 se for int é

Comment: Vc tem algm exemplo ? Pq eu n to conseguindo visualizar oq vc ta falando

Comment: `index = 12`
`teste_mult_de_quatro = index / 4 # teste_mult_de_quatro == 3`
`if type(teste_mult_de_quatro) == int:`
`   print('é multiplo de 4')`
`else:`
   `print('não é multiplo de 4')`

`

Comment: eu tenho q colocar esse codigo junto com o codigo do meu bot ? procurei sobre index no google e no youtube e n teve quase nenhum resultado

Comment: é q o index é para ser a linha q vc ta executando

Comment: Não faço a menor ideia de como fazer isso, vc n conhece nenhum site que ensine sobre index ? Pq eu to procurando mas n acho nd

Comment: https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/a-funcao-enumerate/

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, e me desculpa por não entender oq vc ta a tentando dizer, sou extremamente leigo kkkk e pra mim é ja é um feito muito grande conseguir fazer meu próprio bot lor mais que não esteja completo

Comment: relaxa todos nós ja partimos do zero algum dia, espero que isso te motive a continuar, e se prepare para o mundo duro que é sopt